# How to get return value from a Stored Procedure In Oracle using R?

Tags: r, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a Stored procedure which I execute from R. This SP populates a table with values for a particular date.

The SP comprises of 15 steps, and failing of one results in halting of the execution.

If there is an error, I would like to return 'F' from the SP and take it in a object (say Status) in R.

How can this be done in R?

**Note:** I am using 'ROracle' package.

Comment: You can't "return" values from a stored procedure; it's a procedure not a function and thus doesn't "return" anything... you can use OUT parameters though.

Comment: If the error has as a side effect that nothing has been added to the table you want to populate you could consider to put your sp in a loop together with a dbGetQuery. After  the sp call check with the dbGetQuery if there are values for that date. If not, print ("f")